# Android Kotlin: Creating the file back from string path is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-file

I am working on an Android project using Kotlin. In my project I am trying to create a File object back from string path. This is the string path format.

```
/storage/emulated/0/mediapicker/images/eb162701-f4b7-4d0a-b824-7cc56a7ff926.jpg
```

I tried the following

```
var file = File(path)
var file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), path)
var file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), path)
var file = File(context.filesDir, path)
```

When I run file.exists(), all of them returning false. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you actually have that directory on the device? That path seems suspicious. Of your four `File()` calls, only the first one might be valid. You might also just try opening the file rather than relying on `exists()`. Note that to use this location on Android 10, you need `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in your manifest. And, you need `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` on Android 4.4+ (plus runtime permissions for that on Android 6.0+).

Comment: I am using Android 11 and the permission is granted.

Comment: I put in the android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in the AndroidManifest.xml as well. Any other idea?

Comment: On an Android 11 device you cannot create your own directories in root of external storage. Try `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/mediapicker/images/eb162701-f4b7-4d0a-b824-7cc56a7ff926.jpg` instead.

Comment: And usually you need to obtain WRITE permissions if you want to create a file ;-) But not on Android 11 funny enough.

Comment: I have the write access to the external storage too. :(